# mapbasic code to create 10 points in a single long/lat without overlapping to each other

Tags: mapinfo, map-basic

Good day! I know how to create a points in a mapbasic having a single long/lat, but i wanted to create  10 points on a single coordinates without overlapping to each other but separated by about 5m radius apart from the given coordinates.

Any idea how should i start coding this.

br,
Ivan

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to create 10 points at one position or 10 points at different positions?

Comment: thanks Wernfried. Actually, i only have one coordinates, which i could make a single point, but i have a another column variable value that i wanted to make, to create another points (around the clock) 5 meters apart from the single coordinates.

Comment: Ok, distance of 5 meters. In which direction?

Comment: it is possible around the clock or North/North East/etc. whichever is better.

Answer (score 0):

In principal it looks like this

```
Dim x,y as Float
Dim offset as Integer

offset = 5 'distance 5 meters

'single coordinate
x = 1000
y= 2000

For i = 1 To 10
   Create Point (x + Cos(i * (360/10) * DEG_2_RAD) * offset, y + Sin(i * (360/10) * DEG_2_RAD) * offset)
Next
```

Please note, this works properly only for cartesian coordinate system, e.g. UTM. If you work on Lat/lon you have to do some additinal trigonometry for the offset.

**Update**

Have also a look at function `CartesianOffset( object, angle, distance, units )` and `CartesianOffsetXY( object, xoffset, yoffset, units )`, maybe they are easier to use.

```
Dim obj as Object        
obj = CreatePoint(1000, 2000) 'Start point

For i = 1 To 10
    Create Point(CentroidX(obj), CentroidY(obj))
    obj = CartesianOffset(obj, -10, 5, "m") ' move by 5 meters for -10°
Next
```